# Radio Mic Comparisons....

Tags: radiomics, microphone-technique

Hi all!!

For all those production sound mixers/recorders out there, I'm just after some general input/tips into radio mic selection and techniques?

From my experience, most sound mixers I've come across like to use the Tram Lavalier or the Sanken Cos-11 lav (the latter favoured due to the smaller capsule being easier to hide). Has anybody any other radio mics they prefer to use for production sound/capturing dialogue?

I'm also curious to hear of people's radio micing techniques that are used to optimise dialogue recording but minimising the dreaded clothing/rustling noise! It seems like a rather dark art!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the COS-11 and the Tram 50, other popular choices are the Countryman B6 and the DPA lavs (some also like the smaller Sennheiser models).

As to technique, the best source I know is jwsoundgroup.net. It has an abundance of knowledge on this kind of area, and I know there are even some threads containing links to the biggest discussions about it. Don't use the sites own search engine though, just search within the webpage from google or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Sanken is tried and proven! for most applications. 
B6 is too sensitive in my opinion, sensitive wire and capsule noise.
ME2 is quite good for the budget.

Haven't demo the tram50 and DPA4060.

Rycote stickies and moleskin to conceal the lavs works very well.
Also love using the vampire clips!

@productionsoundtexas